# Positiong multiple trees on a page

Tags: tables

I actually wrote that

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[edges]{forest} 

    \begin{document}



    \section{trees}
    \begin{figure}[!h]
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
      \begin{forest} for tree={draw, semithick, rounded corners, font =                 \sffamily, top color = white, bottom color = white, grow = south, s sep = 4mm, l         sep = 8mm,} [{S}[{C}[{A}[{B}[{H}[{I}]][{I}][{H}[{I}]]][{I}][{H}[{I}]]][{A}[{H}        [{I}]][{I}][{H}[{I}]]]]]; \end{forest}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{0.1cm}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth} 
       \begin{forest} for tree={draw, semithick, rounded corners, font =         \sffamily, top color = white, bottom color = white, grow = south, s sep = 4mm, l         sep = 8mm,} [{S}[{B}[{B}[{H}[{I}]][{I}][{H}[{I}]]][{I}][{H}[{I}]]]];         \end{forest} 
    \end{minipage}        
    \end{figure} 

    \end{document}
```

and i want to obtain something, more or less, like this in the following image
[image]

How i can do a similar table, but more important, how I can fit tree of any dimension in a determined cell?

Comment: Welcome! Why is this tagged `table-of-contents`? Are you using trees to present your contents listings? That is certainly an unusual approach! Could you clarify your question? Are you asking how to scale a tree to fit a certain box size? Or are you asking how to have the cell size scale to fit the tree/ Note that scaling diagrams, especially those which include text, is officially A Bad Idea and should be treated as an option of last resort. That is, are you sure you can't do better?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like this?

[image: table of trees]

The basic idea is that if you want a table, you might as well use a `tabular`. `tabularx` is used to fill the width of the current line, with `\multicolumn`s for a larger tree (here just a repeat of one of the existing trees, so not larger) and text below. Note, however, that the use of vertical rules in tables is not good practice. That said, this may not really be a table as such, so that may be irrelevant.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{forest} 
\usepackage{tabularx,array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\forestset{%
  my tree/.style={
    baseline,
    tikz+={\node [fit to=tree, inner sep=5pt] {};},
    for tree={
      draw, 
      semithick, 
      rounded corners, 
      font = \sffamily, 
%       fill=white, % if presenting on a coloured background
%       top color = white, % these two lines are pointless: shading from white to white is just a white fill; on a white page, this makes no difference
%       bottom color = white, 
%       grow = south, % default 
%       s sep' = 4mm, % if you are trying to save space, the last thing you want is to increase the spaciness of the tree ...
%       l  sep' = 8mm,  & ... in either direction ...
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}

\section{trees}
% don't use figure unless you want it to float away; never use h as the sole location option - it means 'here, if there's space', but what if there isn't space?!'
\begin{tabularx}\linewidth{|C|C|}
  \hline
  \begin{forest} my tree [S[C[A[B[H[I]][I][H[I]]][I][H[I]]][A[H [I]][I][H[I]]]]] \end{forest}
  &
  \begin{forest} 
    my tree
    [S[B[B[H[I]][I][H[I]]][I][H[I]]]]
  \end{forest} \\\hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{  \begin{forest} my tree [S[C[A[B[H[I]][I][H[I]]][I][H[I]]][A[H [I]][I][H[I]]]]] \end{forest}} \\\hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textsf{Something here}} \\\hline
\end{tabularx}  
\end{document}
```

I'm not sure what you mean by a tree of 'any dimension'. Obviously, if a tree is too big, it won't fit. You can scale it, but it is not a great idea to scale diagrams to fit, as you end up with all kinds of font sizes in a weird hodge-podge. If this can't be avoided you can use `\resizebox` from the `graphicx` package, but `tikzscale` offers more palatable options. (However, I can't remember if they work with Forest.)

Before you do that, let Forest do the best it can to produce a compact tree i.e. do **not** increase `l sep` or `s sep`. Second try something like `font=\sffamily\footnotesize` to decrease the font size in a consistent way. This will also give much better results if you are using a font with optical sizes (such as Computer Modern or Latin Modern, although the sans are a bit more restricted, if I remember correctly). This will help avoid the hodge-podge problem by using a standard size and keep line widths constant between diagrams (which specify the same line widths, anyway). Note that, as specified, your trees use a mix of line widths - edges are standard and node borders are `semithick`. I'm not sure if this is intended or not. Add `edge+={semithick}` to `for tree` in the definition of `my tree` if you want `semithick` throughout or delete `semithick if you want the default thickness everywhere.